# Input changes do not occur with default value with @testing-library/react

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have the following input:

```
<input
        name="name"
        type="text"
        data-testid="input"
        onChange={(e) => setTypedName(e.target.value)}
        value=""
      />
```

the test:

```
test.only('Should change the value of the input ', async () => {
    makeSut()
    const nameInput = sut.getByTestId('input') as HTMLInputElement
    fireEvent.change(nameInput, { target: { value: 'value' } })
    expect(nameInput.value).toBe('value')
  })
```

My assertion fails, as the change does not take effect, while the value remains to be `""`

If I remove `value=""` from the `input`, change takes effect.

I have tried using `fireEvent.input` `fireEvent.change`, `userEvent.type` and nothing works.

It seems that when I use a default `value` the testing library does not accept changes, even though it works on production...

Any hints?

Using:

- jest 27.3.1
- @testing-library/react 12.1.2
- @testing-library/user-event 13.5.0

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but perhaps this is due to React relying more on explicitly setting the value of components through JS rather than through "vanilla" HTML.

Explicitly setting the input value through JS makes your test pass:

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

const Component = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  return (
    <input
      name="name"
      type="text"
      data-testid="input"
      onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
      value={value}
    />
  );
};

test.only("Should change the value of the input ", async () => {
  render(<Component />);
  const nameInput = screen.getByTestId("input") as HTMLInputElement;
  userEvent.type(nameInput, "value");
  expect(nameInput.value).toBe("value");
});
```

PS I slightly modified your test to use `render` because I'm not sure what `makeSut` is, and I assume it's some custom function that you created to render your component.

Comment: The original code has the default value set as per on our answer. THe inputs are populated in a form for editing an entity. The issue remains =/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean that you have to use `value=""` and you cannot use `value={value}`?

Comment: what I mean is that the Input's value is populated on ```render``` and I am not able to fire an event to change it's value with ```@testing-library/react```. On production it works flawlessly. This issue only occurs in my testing environment.

Comment: I have tried ```userEvent.type```, ```fireEvent.change``` ```fireEvent.input```, etc. Nothing seems to work. The state does not change. If I rip the prop ```value``` from the ```input``` it works normally on the testing enviro

Comment: it is super weird....

Comment: @Alioshr perhaps this part of the React documentation can be useful for your problem: https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

Comment: To me, `userEvent.type` will append my initial value. So I have to clear it first and then type. `userEvent.clear(); userEvent.type(input, newValue);`